# has_one: through: does not add constructors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through, has-one

I'm fairly new to rails and ActiveRecord and I can't figure out why rails doesn't generate a `User.build_company` method for the following model setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :found_company
  has_one :company, through: :found_company
end

class FoundCompany < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :found_companies
  has_many :users, through: :found_companies
end
```

This is what happens when I try to call the build method:

```
irb(main):035:0> user = User.all.first
    ?[1m?[36mUser Load (1.0ms)?[0m  ?[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" ?[0m
    => #<User id: 1, email: "user@example.com" [...] uid: nil>
    irb(main):036:0> user.build_company
NoMethodError: undefined method `build_company' for #<User:0x5bd50e0>
```

If I change `has_one: through` to `has_many: through` everything works as expected:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :found_companies
  has_many :companies, through: :found_companies
end
```

Invoking user.companies.build works fine:

```
irb(main):041:0> f.companies.build
=> #<Company id: nil, name: nil, created_at:
[...]
irb(main):041:0>
```

Why doesn't `has_one: through` seem to generate the builder methods?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware `user.companies.build` is the correct syntax.  I'm not aware of `.build_company` as a way of instantiation associated items.

Comment: afaik, for has_one and belongs_to associations it's actually build_association and not object.other.build

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Rails doesn't provide the method, you can achieve what you want however by doing the following:

```
user.build_found_company.build_company
```

Comment: Wow, that works but it seems so awkward. Why do I need to deal with the join table explicitly as opposed to has_many where I can access company directly?